# Basic CRUD operations on Azure DB from MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I have built a very basic mvc application.  I need it to have basic CRUD functionality.  My database is located on Azure.  When I try to create a new record in my mvc application it does not load into my Azure database. I followed the tutorial on the Microsoft website for using EF6.  I used scaffolding to create the new view and controller once I connected the Azure database and none of the crud functionality works.  This is the code for the "create" portion

```
        // POST: Venues/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "VenueID,VenueName,VenueAdd,VenueCity,VenueState,VenueCountry,VenueCounty,VenueZip,VenuePhone,VenueFax,VenueContactName,VenueContactEmail,VenueContactPhone,VenueWebsite,VenueLat,VenueLong,VenueRating")] Venue venue)
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Venues.Add(venue);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(venue);
    }
```

It is very basic that is why I am not sure why it isn't working
[This is the link I want to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDJW6.png)

The Azure database is empty.  I have used the ado entity model in visual studio to connect to the database.  It is an .edmx file

ok this may help a lot - I was able to step through the code and I received this exception

> Message = "Unable to update the EntitySet 'Venue' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation."

So it looks as if there is no insert function - at least that is what I am thinking but wasn't that created when I did the scaffolding?

Comment: how the `db` object is created ? how is it connecting to azure?

Comment: I am using EF 6 to connect to the database / azure

Comment: Need more information to answer this. How the `db` object is created ? structure of `Venue` entity? any constrains in `Venue` entity?  worth sharing code snippets.

Comment: I created a blank database on Azure.  I used the built in functionality in visual studio to connect to it using EF6.  I then created the controller and views using scaffolding. The database is empty and all I am trying to do is use the "create new" link that was created in the view to put records into the database.  I will update the question

Comment: ok. that would be helpful.  btw i haven't downvoted your question.

Comment: I have updated the question.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What had happened is somehow the primary key of the model was not created.  I created the primary key and all of the CRUD functionality was there.  Thank you for all the help